# How to avoid duplicate inserts when using updateOne on a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an Mongoose database object which contains a collection that holds "user signatures", where the signature is must to be unique, i.e no duplicates of signatures can appear in the collection.

I have therefor put the `unique: true` flag on the field `signature` in the schema object, but this still don't prevents it from having duplicate, but it do work on `title` 
query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `filter` and include `$elemMatch` condition to make sure that the element you're trying to insert into an array isn't already there:

```
let filter = { _id: id, signatures: { $not: { signature: signature } } };
```

[Mongo Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VJ_b8oon6PR)

So if you're trying to insert a new `signature` the document will be found by `_id` otherwise the filter part will return no matching document and your `update` won't be applied.

Comment: Thanks! It was the filter in the link that worked, not the one in the answer itself.